# How to add columns and Evaluate the value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview (two columns). Columns 1: Name, Columns 2: Age

And I want add more column name Evaluate behind Columns Age when I press Evaluate button.

Content on each row are Young(Old). Young if Age<40 and Old if Age>40
How I do that?

My code:

```
OpenFileDialog opd = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void btnOpenfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Open txt file
        opd.Filter = "TXT|*.txt";
        //Choose File
        if (opd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblFilename.Text = opd.SafeFileName;

        }
        var dulieu = File.ReadAllLines(opd.FileName);
        ////////////////////
        if (dulieu.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var cellValues in dulieu.Skip(0))
             {
            var cellArray = cellValues
                .Split(new[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (cellArray.Length == dtgBangketqua.Columns.Count)
                dtgBangketqua.Rows.Add(cellArray);
             }

        }

    }
```

[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPCof.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `if (cellArray.Length == dtgBangketqua.Columns.Count)` I assume you do not already have a "**Evaluate**" column within your DataGridView.  So first thing to do is add one.

Then loop through each row and obtain the age value.
It originally came in as a string, so, you need to cast it to an int.
Then evaluate the age, I assume you did not mean to exclude people who are exactly 40, so I set that as Old.

Here is the code that should work for your need:

```
private void btnEvaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtgBangketqua.Columns.Add("Evaluate", "Evaluate");

    foreach (DataGridViewRow ThisRow in dtgBangketqua.Rows)
    {
        string strAge = ThisRow.Cells[1].Value as string;
        int Age = -1;
        if( int.TryParse(strAge,out Age) == true )
        {
            ThisRow.Cells[2].Value = (Age < 40) ? "Young" : "Old";
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.